# integrating foreign socket descriptors with twisted reactor

Tags: python, twisted

How do we integrate foreign socket descriptors with twisted reactor. I looked at the serverfactory and protocol classes, there is a dataReceived method for processing the data read from socket, but i dont want twisted to read the data from socket. I just want to be notified when the data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`twisted.internet.interfaces.IReadDescriptor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReadDescriptor.html) (Or [`IWriteDescriptor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IWriteDescriptor.html) or [`IReadWriteDescriptor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReadWriteDescriptor.html)) and use [`IReactorFDSet.addReader`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFDSet.html#addReader) and/or [`addWriter`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFDSet.html#addWriter) to have the reactor monitor the descriptor.

Note this only works for reactors which implement `IReactorFDSet`.  All the ones distributed with Twisted do except for IOCP reactor.